# PagedList null objects for items not on current page

Tags: c#, pagination, asp.net-web-api, pagedlist

I have created a WebApi project designed to search over a data set filtering on various criteria. I'm using PagedList library by Troy Goode for pagination.

Any results that are not meant to be listed on the page shown are listed as null objects as per the example below:

```
{
    "TotalNumberOfPages": 10,
    "TotalNumberOfResults": 10,
    "PageSize": 1,
    "PageNumber": 1,
    "Results": [
        {
            "Foo": "Bar"
        },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]
}
```

I've so far been unable to omit these null values, any suggestions?